# Console output as Tkinter label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a GUI for youtube-dl using Python 3.8 and Tkinter and I wanna add a progress bar, by using the latest line in the console.

For example, this would be the newest line:

```
[download]  27.4% of 519.64KiB at 46.52KiB/s ETA 00:08
```

And in the GUI it would look like this:

[image: (Am not allowed to insert images yet :/)]

My current code looks like this

```
class MainMenu():
    # some code before it
    terminaloutput = subprocess.check_output
    progressbar = Label(window, text=terminaloutput)
    # rest of the code
```

and this

```
def convert():
    MainMenu.progressbar.pack()
    # rest of the code
```

But all that it shows in the GUI is this:

[image: (Once again, no embed images :/)]

Keep in mind, the terminal shows what it's supposed to.

```
[youtube] neq82Pi3jG4: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: /home/markix/Desktop/Retray WR i beat you khasem (642) click Scroll Click.m4a
[download] 100% of 519.64KiB in 00:11
[ffmpeg] Correcting container in "/home/markix/Desktop/Retray WR i beat you khasem (642) click Scroll Click.m4a"
```

So... how do I fix this? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: could you provide complete [mre]? it seems that you would need to check console output periodically

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with separate thread working in background that is responsible for reading output stream of process and modifying text of label.
Something like this

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import threading

class CmdThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, command, textvar):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.command = command
        self.textvar = textvar

   def run(self):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(self.command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        while not proc.poll():
            data = proc.stdout.readline()
            if data:
                print(data)
                self.textvar.set(data)
            else:
                break

window = tk.Tk()
text = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(textvariable=text)
label.pack()

thread = CmdThread(['netstat'], text)
thread.start()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: (In the GUI) it shows "unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     52751"

Comment: so it is ok, because it is probably the last line of netstat command that as an example I used here. Replace it with some other command to have output you need